# Simple CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css

Okay Im terrible at css and desperate for some help. I know this will be simple for someone who is good at it.

I included my code and what Iv been trying, and several pictures of what it looks like. The first picture is what I have. The second is what I want it to look like.

[image: What I have]

[image: What I want it to look like]

HTML

```
    <div class="thumbposter"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/imdb/imdbImage.php?url=http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcwNzUzMjU1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTM0NDQ2MQ@@._V1._SY200.jpg"/><div class="ratingimage"><h1>Step Brothers</h1><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/ratedr.png"></div></div>
    <div class="genre"><p>Genre: Comedy</p></div>
    <div class="releasedate"><p>Released: 2008</p></div>
    <div class="rating"><p>Rating: 6.8</p></div>
    <div class="plot"><h1>Plot</h1><p>Two aimless middle-aged losers still living at home are forced against their will to become roommates when their parents get married.</p></div>
```

CSS

```
<style> 
@font-face
{
    font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
    src: url(http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/font/MyriadPro-Regular.otf);
}


.thumbposter img
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius:2px;
}

.thumbposter h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px; 
    top: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
}

.releasedate p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 323px; 
    top: 295px;
    color: white;
    font-size:15px;
}

.genre p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 323px;
    top: 315px;
    color: white;
    font-size:15px;
}

.rating p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 323px;
    top: 275px;
    color: white;
    font-size:15px;
}

.plot p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px; 
    top: 170px;
    width: 500px;
    color: white;
    font-size:15px;
}

.trailer a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 345px; 
    top: 260px;
    color: white;
    font-size:17px;
}

.playbutton img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 325px; 
    top: 260px;
}

.plot h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px; 
    top: 140px;
    color: white;
    font-size:22px;
}


.ratingimage img {
    position: relative;
    left: 500px; 
    top: 60px;
    float:left;
}


@font-face
{
    font-family: airstrikebold;
    src: url(http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/font/airstrikebold.ttf);
}
</style>
```

I just want the R to go next to the title... As you can see from my code, I am terrible at css and use Absolute positioning for everything, I can not do that with the "R" rating because some titles are longer than others. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a non position:absolute solution:

Also refactored your markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="left">
         <img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/imdb/imdbImage.php?url=http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcwNzUzMjU1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTM0NDQ2MQ@@._V1._SY200.jpg"/>
        <p>Genre: Comedy</p>
        <p>Released: 2008</p>
        <p>Rating: 6.8</p>
    </div><! /.left -->

    <div class="right">
        <h1>Step Brothers <img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/ratedr.png"></h1>

        <h1>Plot</h1>
        <p>Two aimless middle-aged losers still living at home are forced against their will to become roommates when their parents get married.</p>


    </div><!-- /.right --> 

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.left { float:left; width:200px; }
.right { float:left; width:400px; }

.clear { clear:both }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LNmRb/2/)**

Comment: This is clearly a cleaner way. Abusing of the absolute position can make the page breaks in lots of situations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Im terrible at styling and had a brain fart. This organizes things much better

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the first line with :

```
<div class="thumbposter"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/imdb/imdbImage.php?url=http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTcwNzUzMjU1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTM0NDQ2MQ@@._V1._SY200.jpg"/><div class="ratingimage"><h1>Step Brothers <img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/ratedr.png"></h1></div>
```

For sure, you can delete all CSS about rated R image.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ratingimage img {
    /* do not need styling */
}
.thumbposter h1 {
    display: inline; /* add this */

    position: absolute;
    left: 500px; 
    top: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
}
```

should swap the img next to the title. Afterthat, try some additional styling (margin,...) for getting the correct position.